# Content for <compatible-screens> tag to enable only Galaxy S3 and Nexus in Android Manifest file (Titanium Studio)

Tags: android, titanium

What is the content i have to specifiy in android manifest file to make my application
only available to **Galaxy S3 and Nexus 7 users** (and disable all others)

should i use the below

`<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />`

is this correct?

**Note :** I have built my app in Titanium Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the content i have to specifiy in android manifest file to make my application only available to Galaxy S3 and Nexus 7 users (and disable all others)

That is not possible from the manifest.

> is this correct?

The Galaxy S3 is not an `-xlarge` device.

The Nexus 7 is not an `-xlarge` device, nor is it an `-xhdpi` device.

Moreover, even if they were, there are other devices that would have the same specifications.

If you truly wish to limit your app to owners of those two specific devices, as Sabre indicates in the comment, use the Google Play developer console.